# How to replace XML inside of a file that is not entirely XML with PowerShell using return value of *.exe?

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

I have a specially formatted configuration text file that has 1 line that starts with `wcfconfig,Text,<?xml version...` and I'm trying to use PowerShell to replace the entire XML block with one that is returned from an executable.  The text file (ex: C:\Temp\MyText.txt) looks like this:

```
Special Export File
Format: 1
Configuration: MyConfig
    startupcmd,Text,
    extracmdline,Text,
    wsdlport,Text,9500
    useserverprinters,Int,1
    aosencryption,Text,1
    dbserver,Text,Dev-SERVER
    wcfconfig,Text,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><configuration>...
    hint,Text,
```

I have an executable when called with a server/port and returns an XML string.

`C:\MyFile.exe Dev-SERVER 9500`

Where `Dev-Server` is from `dbserver` in the text file and `9500` is from the `wsdlport` in the text file.

It returns an XML string in the exact format as the `wcfconfig` above, that I would just like to replace entirely on the 1 line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <client>
    </client>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your environment I had to fake a couple of things. The output of `C:\MyFile.exe Dev-SERVER 9500` is represented by the here-string `$return`

```
$return = @"
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <client>
    </client>
</configuration>
"@

(Get-Content "C:\Temp\MyText.txt") -replace '^(\s*?wcfconfig,Text,).*',"`$1$($replace -replace "`r`n")"
```

Take the content of the file "C:\Temp\MyText.txt" and use `-replace` to locate the line you are trying to update. Replace it with all the text up until `<?xml` and then append the file data with the new lines removed.

There would be white space between some elements `>     <`. If that is an issue an additional `-replace` should handle that. `-replace "\>\s+?\<","><"`